# Auto click on button like in ifarme when page load

Tags: php, angularjs, node.js, laravel

If I wanted to auto-click a button element in ifarme how would I go about this working ?

```js
function autoclick() {
document.getElementById('u_0_4').contentWindow.document.getElementById("u_0_5").click()
}
```

```html
<div onload="autoclick()" >
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.facebook.com%2FMaherZain&width=450&layout=standard&action=like&size=small&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80&appId=788255487990117" width="450" height="80" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" id="u_0_4" ></iframe>
  
  </div>
```

=====> if have any other way for do that please tell me :(

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that because otherwise people would just embed a 1x1 iframe and have every visitor "Like" whatever the author wanted. It's a security issue to let different origins have access to the `contentWindow` of iframes pointing to a different origin.

Imagine if you **were** able to do that. People could just start embedding gmail or your banking website in a 1x1 iframe and then trigger a few clicks and keyboard events to reset your password.

Comment: =====> if have any other way for do that please tell me :(

Comment: @Simo you could make the iframe transparent and then keep it positioned under the user's cursor. Then the user would end up clicking the button inside the iframe the first time they clicked on the screen.

Comment: but when i do that , the borwser open other window for user have button confirm , tel the user confirm like how i can fix that for not to give the user other window , and the like be done ?
have any way for skip the confirm and the like be done ?